# Number of counterexamples which prove that the squared distance from the origin of a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$is not Markovian

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

**Notations**

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two simple random walks on the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. So the process $\{(X_n,Y_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, where each step the "increment" of the couple of random variables could be $(+1,+1),(+1,-1),(-1,+1),(-1,-1)$ with uniform probability ($\frac{1}{4}$ each). $(X_0,Y_0) = (0,0)$, so we start our random walk from the origin.

**Solved question**

In Nicolas Privault's "Understanding Markov Chains" , the exercise 4.5 wants me to prove or disprove that the stochastic process $Z_n = X_n^2+Y_n^2$ is a Markov chain. I manage to prove with a counterexample that the Markovian property is not always satisfied. For example:

$$
P(Z_n = 122|Z_{n-1} = 100, Z_{n-2} = 98) = 0
$$
while
$$
P(Z_n = 122|Z_{n-1} = 100, Z_{n-2} = 82) > 0
$$
so the "future" of the process depends on the "present" and also on the "past".

**Real question, which generalizes the first one**

How many of these counterexamples exist? Can you find any others? Are there infinitely many of them?

I'll try to write a code to brute force them and I also will try to find some "criteria" in order to eliminate some cases.

**Solution of the first part**

The identities above are true since:

$Z_n = 122$ has solutions $(X_n,Y_n) = (\pm 11,\pm 1)$, $(X_n,Y_n) = (\pm 1,\pm 11)$;

$Z_{n-1} = 100$ has solutions $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 10,0)$, $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (0,\pm 10)$, $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 8,\pm 6)$, $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 6,\pm 8)$;

$Z_{n-2} = 98$ has solutions $(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (\pm 7, \pm 7)$;

$Z_{n-2} = 82$ has solutions $(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (\pm 9, \pm 1)$, $(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (\pm 1, \pm 9)$.

So in the first case we know that $Z_{n-2} = 98$ and $Z_{n-1} = 100$, but this implies that $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 8,\pm 6)$ or $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 6,\pm 8)$, but it's impossible for example that $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 10,0)$, because of the previous value of $Z_{n-2} = 100$ and the fact that $|X_{n+1}-X_n| = |Y_{n+1}-Y_n| = 1$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But since we have proved that $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 8,\pm 6)$ or $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (\pm 6,\pm 8)$, then it's impossible for $Z_n$ to be $122$, just looking at the integer solutions of $X_n^2+Y_n^2 = 122$. So the first probability is equal to 0.

For the second one, we can just prove that it's strictly positive, for example exhibiting a possible path for the process which links the two states:

$(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (9,1) \implies Z_{n-2} = 82$;

$(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (10,0) \implies Z_{n-1} = 100$;

$(X_{n},Y_{n}) = (11,1) \implies Z_{n} = 122$;

**Claim**

If $Z_{n-1} = 4c^2$ where $z$ is the biggest entry in a Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$, then there exist $Z_n$,$Z_{n-2}'$,$Z_{n-2}''$ which forms a valid counterexample.

In the example above, $(3,4,5)$ is the Pythagorean triple and $Z_{n-1} = 4\cdot5^2 = 100$.

**Proof**

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a Pythagorean triple. Let $Z_{n-1} = 4c^2$.
Then $Z_{n-1} = (2c)^2+0^2 = (2a)^2+(2b)^2$.
Let $Z_n = (2c+1)^2+1^2$, $Z_{n-2}' = (2c-1)^2+1^2$, $Z_{n-2}'' = (2a-1)^2+(2b-1)^2$. Then:
$$
P(Z_n|Z_{n-1}, Z_{n-2}') > 0
$$
$$
P(Z_n|Z_{n-1}, Z_{n-2}'') = 0
$$

Then the second probability is equal to 0 because:

$(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (2a-1,2b-1)$ -> $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (2a,2b)$ -> $(X_n,Y_n) = (2c+1,1)$, but the last arrow is impossible since $b\not = -1,0,1$, or in other words $2b$->$1$ in one step of length 1 is impossible.

The other probability is strictly bigger than 0 because of the existence of the following path:

$(X_{n-2},Y_{n-2}) = (2c-1,1)$ -> $(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1}) = (2c,0)$ -> $(X_n,Y_n) = (2c+1,1)$